# Any program for conformational searching for sugars?

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics, conformers

I want to estimate mean Gibbs free energy of formation of glucose and for that purpose I think conformers of [ring flip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_flip) should be taken into account. Do you know if some free program can find those structures automatically? (for example Balloon).

[The following image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_flip#/media/File:Ring-Flip.png) shows the conformers I need to get. I am trying to avoid the possibility of drawing it.

[image: ring flip by Jawero from Wikipedia]

Comment: I use RDKit for conformation searching.  More info here https://proteinsandwavefunctions.blogspot.dk/2016/08/conformer-search-with-rdkit.html

Comment: I'm sorry (new to chemistry here, but your question is interesting to me and I would like some clarification.) Are you asking for software that will generate conformers for you? (Just thought it was a cool question and wanted clarity.)

Comment: @MelanieShebel yes, some free programs that can do that are: balloon and RDkit, you can download them in the web. Also avogadro can do that, although I never try it :)..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use RDKit**

It sounds like you're only considering free or open source conformer generation tools. In that case, I highly recommend using RDKit, since the distance-geometry (and in turn ETKDG) methods will intrinsically generate all possible ring geometries. That includes not just the two chair forms you indicate, but all possible ring-puckering forms.

There are other free tools which do this, but RDKit has been repeatedly shown to be the best or among the best free conformer generation tools. (Based on current benchmarks.)

- ["High-Quality Dataset of Protein-Bound Ligand Conformations and Its Application to Benchmarking Conformer Ensemble Generators." *J Chem Inf Model* **2017** *57*, 529-539.](http://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.6b00613)
- ["Freely Available Conformer Generation Methods: How Good Are They?" *J Chem Inf Model* **2012**, *52* (5), 1146–1158.](http://doi.org/10.1021/ci2004658)

I'd advocate the newer ETKDG method with RDKit, since it seems to produce somewhat better geometries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. As far as I know RDkit doesn't move B-A-O-H diedrals(doesn't see hydrogens), and also doesn't find conformers for ciclohexane. Have you tried that?

Comment: With most conformer programs, the hydrogens are added at the end. As for cyclohexane, yes RDKit can generate multiple different conformers.

Comment: Is it possible to add hydrogens to oxygen and nitrogen before the conf search for those programs? Otherwise, I think some relevant structures will be missed, mainly in sugars.

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of a program that does that, unless you want to run a PMF yourself, but, on the side, here is a systematic study of the energetics of monosaccharide sugar puckering: Heather B. Mayes, Linda J. Broadbelt, and Gregg T. Beckham, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2014,** *136* (3), 1008–1022. DOI: [10.1021/ja410264d](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja410264d). You may find here the info you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. We prefer to use human-readable references and non-pdf links, I have edited your post accordingly.

Comment: great!Thanks Elisa. Would you clarify `PMF`?

Comment: PMF stands for potential of mean force. Here is a review you may find interesting, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/001046559500053I